# Check if input element is in class or not in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to see if an input is in a class or not looking by the input

I want by this html code where the input is in a class

```
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="realname">
</div>
```

the result true

And by this html code where the input is outside a class

```
<div class="input-container"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
```

the result false

The input I will get with this javascript code

```
element.closest('form').querySelector('input[name=' + name + ']')
```

Comment: "is in a class" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: Use the (poorly-named...) `HTMLElement.closest(selector)` method to find the closest ancestor element which matches a CSS selector - or use `HTMLElement.parentElement.matches(selector)` if you want to test only the element's parent element and not any other ancestors.

Comment: `element.closest('form').querySelector('input[name=' + name + ']')` <-- This won't work if `name` contains special characters - you need to use `CSS.escape` and use `"` to delimit the attribute value in the selector, like so: ``element.closest('form').querySelector('input[name="' + CSS.escape( name )+ '"]')

Comment: why isn't it just `element.closest('.input-container')` ???

Answer (score 2):

You can make a simple check with `querySelector`:

```js
if (document.querySelector('.input-container [name="realname"]')) {
  console.log('in')
}
else if (document.querySelector('[name="realname"]')) {
  console.log('out')
}
else {
  console.log('[name="realname"] does not exist')
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="realname">
</div>
```

Comment: the second `if` condition will always return true... remove it

Comment: @SalmanA not if the element does not exist at all

Comment: Best practice: Always include the curly braces around branches, even when the branch only contains one statement because you never know if that will change in the future and, if so, and if the braces aren't added at that time, the first statement may or may not execute, but the subsequent one(s) would always execute.

Comment: @ScottMarcus see the update: added curly braces and a final else block to show a message if element does not exist.

Comment: Another best practice: always end your statements with a semicolon because there are cases where the automatic semicolon insertion will not interpret the code correctly and could cause an invocation when none should occur.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to see if an input is in a class or not looking by the input

I think what you *meant* to say this instead:

> I need to check if the immediate-parent HTML element of an `<input>` element has a specific CSS class-name applied to it"

...and that's simple enough:

```js
const inputEl = element.closest('form').querySelector('input[name="' + CSS.escape( name ) + '"]');

const inputElIsChildOfDivWithInputContainerCssClass = inputEl.parentElement.matches('.input-container');

console.log( "result: %o", inputElIsChildOfDivWithInputContainerCssClass );
```

- `Element.matches`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches
- `CSS.escape`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape_static

Comment: @SalmanA I can't choose for one answer, that I believe that's the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) then why not:

```
element.closest(".input-container") !== null ? "in" : "out"
```

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
    console.log(event.target.closest(".input-container") !== null ? "in" : "out");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="i am in">
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="i am out">
```